# Incluir varios elementos no Array

Tags: array

Estou tentando carregar um Array com os elementos que estão em uma variável.
Já tentei de várias formas mas não estou conseguindo.
Segue um print do meu código com o Debug.
Agradeço a ajuda.
Eduardo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ser visto nesse print ele está considerando a string como um único elemento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não utilize imagens. Coloque o seu código executável e minimamente testável.

Comment: A posição 1 do seu Array é uma String e você quer converter o resultado dessa posição pra 1 Array é isso ?

Comment: Não Ricardo... eu precisava converter todos os elementos do Array. Mas isso já foi resolvido com a reposta abaixo. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quem interessar possa, eu resolvi o problema com a instrução :

```
var c = WWArrayY.map(Number);
arrayY = c;
```